# Sqlalchemy drop_all(engine) Oracle sequence is not dropped

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

With Python + Sqlalchemy + Oracle, trying to drop all tables and recreate them. Using oracle sequence in Id column for autoincreament,but drop all is not dropping sequence.

```
engine = create_engine('oracle://user:pass@host:port/db', 
                   implicit_returning=False, 
                   echo=False)

Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

if DROP_AND_CREATE:
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)

meta_data = MetaData()
meta_data = Base.metadata

from domains import users

meta_data.create_all(engine, checkfirst=False)
```

domain package sample,

```
class Users(Base):

__tablename__ = 'users'

id = Column(Integer, Sequence('users_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
name = Column(String(255))
```

in the above all tables are dropped except I can see the sequences I am using are still present in oracle db. if i manually delete them and run again they are running fine.

The user_id_seq created in oracle is not getting dropped. please help.

Error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
 [SQL: 'CREATE SEQUENCE user_queries_id_seq']
```

Comment: not familiar with sqlalchemy, but what if that sequence was used by other objects?

Comment: @tbone in my application i am using the sequence only for that table

Comment: Hi, I guess my point was, there are db objects that "belong" to a table and aren't made to be usable by other objects, like a table trigger or an index.  A sequence is more generic, and isn't necessarily only used by 1 table (it can be part of other procedures/functions, etc).  So are you sure sqlalchemy is supposed to drop this sequence when you drop the table?

Comment: Maybe take a look to [this recipe](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/DropEverything) from SQLAlchemy wiki. It does not include sequences but you could easily adapt it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after few hours of googling... still learning the language and framework., but this code works and does exactly what i want in my application...

Thanks all

```
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

from domains import users

if DROP_AND_CREATE:
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)

logger.info('Creating all registered tables.')
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
```